# Scala 3 Inline Extension for Opaque Type

Tags: scala, scala-3

To reproduce this problem, I need three files:

Part A

```scala
class ImplA:
  def doIt(): Boolean = false

opaque type A <: AnyRef = ImplA

object A:

  extension (inline x: A)
    inline def fun(): Boolean = x.doIt()
```

Part B

```scala
class ImplB extends ImplA

opaque type B <: A = ImplB & A
```

Part C

```scala
def funB(x: B): Unit =
  println(x.fun())
```

As stated, I cannot compile this code. The error is

```
E050] Type Error: ...
  println(x.fun())
          ^^^^^^^
          expression does not take parameters
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Inline stack trace
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
This location contains code that was inlined from ProblemPartA.scala:12
    inline def fun(): Boolean = x.doIt()
                                ^^^^^^
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Explanation (enabled by `-explain`)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 You have specified more parameter lists than defined in the method definition(s).
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I found two different ways to compile.

- Option A: Replace `println(x.fun())` with `println((x: A).fun())` in Part C.
- Option B: Remove both `inline` modifiers from Part A.

But I am not a fan of these options.
Any idea about what the problem is? Is this a compiler bug or a documented feature/limitation of `inline`?

I have tried Scala versions `3.4.0-RC1-bin-20240104-2746ee8-NIGHTLY`, `3.4.0-RC1`, and `3.3.1`.